# My webpage is not updating based on the JSON I import into it

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a webpage that is templated so my javascript can access its elements selectively to fill them in. I also have written a small JSON file that I want to import into my javascript and plug in fields from this JSON file into my HTML elements.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic JSON Events</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&family=ZCOOL+QingKe+HuangYou&display=swap');

        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(26, 20, 33, 0.8);
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: 
            'header header header header header'
            'navbar mbody mbody mbody mbody'
            'navbar mbody mbody mbody mbody'
            'navbar mbody mbody mbody mbody'
            'fnotes fnotes fnotes fnotes fnotes';
            gap: 1%;
            padding: 1%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }


        @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            html {
                aspect-ratio: 1024/768;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
            html {
                aspect-ratio: 375/812;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }

        #title {
            grid-area: header;
            font-family:'ZCOOL QingKe HuangYou', cursive;
            color: rgb(233,178,77);
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 48px;;
        }

        #name-color {
            color: rgb(236, 86, 125);
            font-style: normal;
        }

        :hover #title {
            color: rgb(115, 229, 158);
        }

        #site-nav {
            grid-area: navbar;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #main {
            grid-area: mbody;
            color:ghostwhite;
            font-family: 'Libre Baskerville';
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 5%;
        }

        #footer {
            grid-area: fnotes;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Hello my name is <em id="name-color">Anton</em></h1>
    <time id="timestamp">

    </time>
    <nav role="navigation" id="site-nav">
        <ul id="sitemap">

        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main role="main" id="main">

    </main>
    <footer role="contentinfo" id="footer">
        <section id="content-info" role="contentinfo">

        </section>
        <form id="contact-form" role="form">

        </form>
    </footer>
<script src="./jsofun.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "title" : "First blog post using JSON",
    "timestamp": "",
    "sitemap": {
        "Homepage":"../index.html",
        "Cryptography": "./Cryptography/index.html",
        "Homework": "../cs212/homework/",
        "Minecraft": "./minecraft.html"
        },
    "main": [
        "This was my first attempt at creating a dynamic templated web page which I am going to be",
        "using to refine and form a blog. This post was parsed entirely from JSON and templated",
        "into my webpage. I am excited to learn more about how this can play into even more dynamic",
        "websites and even network driven events when using <em>encoding/json</em> in my GoLang backend."
    ],
        "contact_form": {},
        "content_info": ""
}
```

Javascript:

```
// import json
require('./post1.json');

// read document elements
var title = window.document.getElementById("title");
var timestamp = window.document.getElementById("timestamp");
var sitemap = window.document.getElementById("sitemap");
var main = window.document.getElementById("main");
var contact_form = window.document.getElementById("contact-form");
var content_info = window.document.getElementById("content-info");

// template in json data
title.textContent = data.title;
timestamp.textContent = String(Date.now());
main.textContent = _main.join();

// log json object for debugging
console.log(data);
```

When I test in my terminal using node to see whether my script is importing the JSON correctly with this code:

```
var data = require('./post1.json');
console.log(data);
```

It successfully returns my object how I would expect:

```
[
  {
    title: 'First blog post using JSON',
    timestamp: '',
    sitemap: {
      Homepage: '../index.html',
      Cryptography: './Cryptography/index.html',
      Homework: '../cs212/homework/',
      Minecraft: './minecraft.html'
    },
    main: [
      'This was my first attempt at creating a dynamic templated web page which I am going to be',
      'using to refine and form a blog. This post was parsed entirely from JSON and templated',
      'into my webpage. I am excited to learn more about how this can play into even more dynamic',
      'websites and even network driven events when using <em>encoding/json</em> in my GoLang backend.'
    ],
    contact_form: {},
    content_info: ''
  }
]
```

However, when I use my full script above to try and then place the object elements into my HTML elements nothing happens or changes on my webpage. I even have tried to completely clear the cache using browser settings and then reloading. One thing I noticed is my browser console tells me require() is not defined; this confuses me because I am testing this locally with the commands `npx serve` and `serve` which are both nodejs commands. Node JS is what is supposed to have require defined and able to use so what exactly am I doing wrong here? I use firefox to test this if that changes anything. This is using plain HTML and JavaScript with a node backend, I do not want to use AJAX or any form of XML.

EDIT: Also I want to note, the reason I want to store these objects in external JSON objects is because I would like to use a JSON database which my javascript can dynamically query to form blog posts rather than hardcoding in a JavaScript object into my script for each and every post I want to make. This way I can later make these JSON files locally and add them when I would like without rewriting a webpage every time.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH9tO.png)

Comment: It looks to me as your json is wrapped in an array, thats why `title.textContent = data.title;` don't work, try to call `title.textContent = data[0].title;` see if that works.

Comment: I tried without wrapping the main json in an array as in: ```{json stuff here}``` and it did not work that way either which is why I wrapped it in the array [{}]. I tried using the indexing method you mentioned but still the same result and nothing about the html changes to reflect in my browser.

Comment: I added a note with a screenshot of my browser and console with that change, still the same issue where it says require isnt defined, however I am using node so why wouldn't it be defined?

Comment: You could use somthing like fetch instead, `fetch("test.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));` that will give you the json in an async way.

Comment: `require()` is not a standard javascript API, it is from Node.js. If you are running your javascript in a browser it won't work.

Comment: I don't think browsers can `import` .json either - only javascript - use fetch as already recommended

Comment: Using fetch seems to at least show me the imported Object in the browser console which is a good step, what name can I reference this object by when accessing it this way? I tried to reference it like ```title.textContent = response.title``` and ```title.textContent = data.title``` but the console states that neither variable is defined. However I use ```console.log(data);``` right after and it returns the object in my console with no problems.

Comment: Here's a quick [fetch tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/) to get you started